# Cannot hover on the last point on area chart in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to add a tooltip to the line-area chart using D3.js. When I hover on the last point it is not showing the tooltip. Sometimes, when I hover on the first point it is showing the focus on the last point.

```js
var bardata = [{
    "x": "Oct 2021",
    "ale": 675212,
    "y": 3
  },
  {
    "x": "Aug 2021",
    "ale": 1563310,
    "y": 3
  },
  {
    "x": "Jul 2021",
    "ale": 10988590,
    "y": 17
  },
  {
    "x": "Jun 2021",
    "ale": 19192110,
    "y": 29
  },
  {
    "x": "May 2021",
    "ale": 13598340,
    "y": 17
  },
  {
    "x": "Apr 2021",
    "ale": 7398680,
    "y": 10
  },
  {
    "x": "Mar 2021",
    "ale": 6056660,
    "y": 7
  },
  {
    "x": "Feb 2021",
    "ale": 10024680,
    "y": 17
  },
  {
    "x": "Jan 2021",
    "ale": 6679170,
    "y": 10
  },
  {
    "x": "Dec 2020",
    "ale": 6474480,
    "y": 9
  },
  {
    "x": "Nov 2020",
    "ale": 10866050,
    "y": 13
  },
  {
    "x": "Oct 2020",
    "ale": 7460970,
    "y": 11
  },
  {
    "x": "Sep 2020",
    "ale": 2383820,
    "y": 3
  },
  {
    "x": "Aug 2020",
    "ale": 5974840,
    "y": 12
  },
  {
    "x": "Jul 2020",
    "ale": 13438210,
    "y": 20
  },
  {
    "x": "Jun 2020",
    "ale": 9546280,
    "y": 13
  },
  {
    "x": "May 2020",
    "ale": 6316950,
    "y": 11
  },
  {
    "x": "Apr 2020",
    "ale": 6680440,
    "y": 9
  },
  {
    "x": "Mar 2020",
    "ale": 4834840,
    "y": 7
  },
  {
    "x": "Feb 2020",
    "ale": 1002110,
    "y": 2
  },
  {
    "x": "Jan 2020",
    "ale": 5725130,
    "y": 8
  },
  {
    "x": "Dec 2019",
    "ale": 1828710,
    "y": 3
  },
  {
    "x": "Nov 2019",
    "ale": 661400,
    "y": 2
  },
  {
    "x": "Oct 2019",
    "ale": 963020,
    "y": 1
  },
  {
    "x": "Sep 2019",
    "ale": 603200,
    "y": 1
  },
  {
    "x": "Jul 2019",
    "ale": 2186620,
    "y": 2
  },
  {
    "x": "Jun 2019",
    "ale": 984710,
    "y": 1
  },
  {
    "x": "Apr 2019",
    "ale": 240800,
    "y": 1
  },
  {
    "x": "Feb 2019",
    "ale": 844000,
    "y": 2
  },
  {
    "x": "Jan 2019",
    "ale": 864400,
    "y": 2
  }
]

function draw_areachart(placeholder, bardata) {
  var clicked = false;
  const margin = {
    top: 10,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 26,
    right: 0
  };
  d3.select(placeholder).select('svg').remove()
  $('.trend_tip').remove()
  var width = $('.bar_chrt').width() - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = $('.bar_chrt').height() - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  const svg = d3.select(placeholder)
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', '100%')
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + (width + margin.left + margin.right) + " " + (height + margin.top + margin.bottom))
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)
    .classed("svg-content", true)

  var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%b %Y");

  svg.append("linearGradient")
    .attr("id", "gradient_area")
    .attr('x1', '0%')
    .attr('y1', '100%')
    .attr('x2', '0%')
    .attr('y2', '0%')
    .selectAll("stop")
    .data([{
        offset: "0%",
        color: "rgba(181,31,62)",
        opacity: 0
      },
      {
        offset: "100%",
        color: "#CB1F40",
        opacity: 1
      }
    ])
    .enter().append("stop")
    .attr("offset", function(d) {
      return d.offset;
    })
    .attr("stop-color", function(d) {
      return d.color;
    })
    .attr('style', function(d) {
      return `stop-color:${d.color};stop-opacity:${d.opacity}`;
    });

  var parsedData = bardata.map(val => ({
    count: val.y,
    close: val.ale,
    date: parseTime(val.x),
    cur_date: val.x
  }));

  parsedData = parsedData.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.date - b.date;
  });

  const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([
      d3.min(parsedData.map(d => d.date)),
      d3.max(parsedData.map(d => d.date))
    ])
    .range([0, width]);

  const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(parsedData.map(d => d.close))])
    .range([height, 0]);

  const line = d3.line()
    .x(d => xScale(d.date))
    .y(d => yScale(d.close))
    .curve(d3.curveCatmullRom.alpha());

  const area = d3.area()
    .x(d => xScale(d.date))
    .y0(height)
    .y1(d => yScale(d.close))
    .curve(d3.curveCatmullRom.alpha());

  svg.append("path")
    .datum(parsedData)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area)
    .attr('fill', 'url(#gradient_area)')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1.5);

  svg.selectAll('.line')
    .data([{
      values: parsedData
    }])
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', d => line(d.values))
    .attr('stroke-width', '2')
    .style('fill', 'none')
    // .style('filter', 'url(#glow)')
    .attr('stroke', '#F72047');
  var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .style("display", "none");

  focus.append("line")
    .attr("class", "x-hover-line hover-line")
    .attr("y1", -height * 2)
    .attr("y2", height);

  focus.append("line")
    .attr("class", "y-hover-line hover-line")
    .attr("x1", width)
    .attr("x2", width)

  focus.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 6)
    .style('fill', 'white');

  var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip trend_tip")
    .style("opacity", 1);

  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style('fill', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)')
    .style('cursor', 'pointer')
    .on("mouseover", function() {
      focus.style("display", null);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      if (clicked) return
      $('.trend_tip').hide();
      focus.style("display", "none");
    })
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
    .on("click", click);

  var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }).left

  function click() {
    clicked = true
    $('.trend_tip').hide()
    var x0 = xScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
      i = bisectDate(parsedData, x0, 1),
      d0 = parsedData[i - 1],
      d1 = parsedData[i],
      d = x0 - d0.xScale > d1.xScale - x0 ? d1 : d0;
    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + xScale(d.date) + "," + yScale(d.close) + ")");
    var sel_date = d.date
    filter_options['observe_date>~'] = [moment(new Date(sel_date.getFullYear(), sel_date.getMonth(), 1)).format('YYYYMMDD')]
    filter_options['observe_date<~'] = [moment(new Date(sel_date.getFullYear(), sel_date.getMonth() + 1, 0)).format('YYYYMMDD')]
    updateParams(false, true, true)
    order_bclist('date')
    draw_breadcrumb()
    $('.area_reset').removeClass('invisible')
  }

  function mousemove() {
    if (clicked) return
    $('.trend_tip').hide()
    var x0 = xScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
      i = bisectDate(parsedData, x0, 1),
      d0 = parsedData[i - 1],
      d1 = parsedData[i],
      d = x0 - d0.xScale > d1.xScale - x0 ? d1 : d0;
    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + xScale(d.date) + "," + yScale(d.close) + ")");
    tooltip.html(
        '<div class="tooltip-content p-2"><p class="fs-10 mb-1"><span class="fs-9 opacity-50 mr-1 text-uppercase">Month:</span>' +
        d.cur_date + '</p><p class="fs-10 mb-1"><span class="fs-9 opacity-50 mr-1 text-uppercase">Value:</span>' + d
        .count + '</p><p class="fs-10 mb-1"><span class="fs-9 opacity-50 mr-1 text-uppercase">Total ALE:</span>' +
        '$' + numeral(d.close).format('0,0') + '</p></div>')
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 80) + "px");
    focus.select(".x-hover-line").attr("y2", height - yScale(d.close));
    focus.select(".y-hover-line").attr("x2", width + width);
    $('.trend_tip').show()
  }
  var interval = 6
  const tick = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(10, ${height})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(interval)).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b\'%y')))
    .selectAll('.tick')
    .style('transition', '.2s')
  svg.append('g')
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(5).tickFormat(function(d) {
      return d / 1000000 + 'M'
    }))
    .selectAll('.tick')
    .attr('class', 'tick_y')
    .style('transition', '.2s')
    .style('stroke-width', '0')

  d3.selectAll('g.tick_x text')
    .style('stroke', 'none')
    .style('fill', "rgba(255,255,255,0.55)")
    .style('font-family', "'metropolisregular', sans-serif")
    .style('font-size', "9px")
    .style('text-anchor', 'end');
  d3.selectAll('g.tick_y text')
    .style('stroke', 'none')
    .style('fill', "rgba(255,255,255,0.55)")
    .style('font-family', "'metropolisregular', sans-serif")
    .style('font-size', "9px")
    .style('text-anchor', 'end');

  var tickTexts = svg.selectAll('.tick text')
  tickTexts
    .style('fill', "rgba(255,255,255,0.55)")
    .style('font-family', "'metropolisregular', sans-serif")
    .style('font-size', "9px")
    .attr('text-anchor', function(d, i) {
      if (i == interval - 1) {
        return 'end'
      }
      return 'middle'
    })
    .attr('dx', function(d, i) {
      if (i == interval - 1) {
        return '0.8em'
      }
      return ''
    });

  tick
    .selectAll('line')
    .attr('stroke-dasharray', `5, 5`)
    .attr('stroke', 'none')
    .attr('y2', `-${height}px`)

  tick
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', `${(width / 12) + 10}px`)
    .attr('x', `-${width / 24 + 5}px`)
    .attr('y', `-${height}px`)
    .attr('height', `${height + 30}px`)
    .style('cursor', 'pointer');

  svg.selectAll('.domain')
    .attr('stroke', 'none')
}
draw_areachart('.bar_chrt', bardata)
```

```css
.bar_chrt {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px
}

body {
  background: black;
}

.trend_tip {
  position: absolute;
}

.tooltip-content {
  border: solid 1px grey;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.15.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>

<div class="bar_chrt"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, the tooltip doesn't seem to work at all in the snippet, or in [the codepen](https://codepen.io/wittybutterfly/pen/VwMYrXz?editors=1111) you linked before. Could you check whether you missed anything? Also, it's a lot of code right now, could you try to strip it down to a [mre]? It will definitely improve the quality and likelihood of an answer

Comment: @RubenHelsloot Sorry for this. I have updated the code in the Codepen.

Comment: Thanks! Please try to strip it down more though, removing for example the `clicked` logic, the styling of the ticks, and the gradient area under the plot. Unless one of those things causes the issue (I highly doubt it), they make the question more difficult to understand

Comment: I tried to remove all the code here, but was not able to change that. Sorry :( @RubenHelsloot